# Calculate value based on previous day without using a join

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a table below that is filled with some example data. I want to create a new attribute 2_day_state. 2_day_state looks at State for each row and compare it with the similar row for the previous day. There are several case statements for how 2_day_state is calculated depending on the values for two following days. E.g. We determine the value for 2_day_state (for day 2) depending on state for day 1 and 2.

It seems like a simple task where we can perform a self join to achieve this.
In practice this table has many attributes that are a part of the key. Some of them can have value null. Since we cant join null=null there must be another way to calculate 2_day_state. Any ideas?

- Day     State
- Day= 1, State= 7
- Day= 2, State= 1
- Day= 3, State= 4
- Day= 4, State= 0

Comment: Did you try an Analytic Function, `MIN(col) OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2, col3 ORDER BY col4)`? Can you show some example rows plus expected result?

Comment: @Rabbit: In Teradata it seems like it's impossible to join on a=b (if a and b are null). I think i know how to solve it though. I can't verify it though. Instead JOIN ON COALESCE(a,'value')=COALESCE(b,'value)

Comment: No DBMS will join on NULLs. Instead of `COALESCE` better use @Rabbit's `OR`-condition, which result in better performance...

Answer (score 0):

Not true, you can join nulls: `ON table1.ID = table2.ID AND (table1.field1 = table2.field2 OR (table1.field1 IS NULL AND table2.field2 IS NULL))`. On another note, you really should avoid keys where values can be null.